# Representation between two groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, definition, group-homomorphism

I know that my question may seem very silly, but I would like to get a clear image for the definition of a representation between two groups.

Let $G$, $H$ be two groups and $T:G \longrightarrow H$ a representation.

Does that mean that $T$ is just a group homomorphism between the two groups $G$ and $H$?

Are there more conditions imposed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "representation between two groups". Usually, a representation of a group $G$ is a morphism from $G$ to a group of automorphisms. For example, a linear representation of $G$ would be a morphism from $G$ to $GL(V)$ where $V$ is a vector space.

Comment: So where did you come across the phrase "representation between two groups"?